# How do I log in to AWS Console with an IAM user account?

Tags: security, authentication, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have created an IAM user account. Now I want to connect with this user to the AWS console.

AWS says:

> For Users who need access to the AWS Management Console, create a password in the Users panel after completing this wizard.

I have created one password for the IAM user.

Trying to log in to the AWS Console using the new user name and the password does not work.

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

If you do not have the AWS Alias Configured then you would use

**https://Your_AWS_Account_ID.signin.aws.amazon.com/console/**

if an alias is configure then

**https://Your_Alias.signin.aws.amazon.com/console/**

Apparently the URL for the AWS IAM Login is quite hard to remember. I have created this site to navigate to the respective IAM Console's Login page by just remembering the alias or the account number.

> [**https://github.com/naveen-vijay/awsiamlogin**](https://github.com/naveen-vijay/awsiamlogin)

[image]

Comment: Glad I was able to help you. PS: it is open source - https://github.com/naveen-vijay/awsiamlogin     Please contribute, if you can

Comment: Thank you, that's a very useful tool. I've spent 5 min trying to login to my account, even starting from the official AWS home page I couldn't (maybe due to some cookie issue). Anyway, using this IAM login page it went right away to the right place.

Answer (score 13):

Found it!

One has to log in using the login URL that is available in the IAM Dashboard or create a personalised login URL as described here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccountAlias.html

Answer (score 5):

I had to add @{your Account#} to log in using IAM, like so:

> https://Your_Alias@Account.signin.aws.amazon.com/console/